# Find record with certain number of matches on one FK, has-many :through association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, performance, activerecord

I have a has_many :through association between players and teams. This is a many-to-many relationship where each team can have any number of players and vice versa.

I want to be able to find a record with a certain number of matches on the same foreign key. In this context, I want to find the team with a certain set of players within it. This can be either inclusive or exclusive:

1. Return teams that consist only of players ids 11 and 12.
2. Return teams that have any number of players, including player ids 11 and 12.

```
    # player.rb
    class Player < ApplicationRecord
        has_many :PlayerLinks
        has_many :teams, through: :PlayerLinks
    end

    # team.rb
    class Team < ApplicationRecord
          has_many :PlayerLinks, dependent: :destroy
          has_many :players, through: :PlayerLinks
    end
```

If I was writing this with SQL I would probably do it with aliases

```
SELECT * 
    FROM Team 
        JOIN PlayerLink AS pl1 ON Team.id = pl1.team_id 
        JOIN PlayerLink AS pl2 ON Team.id = pl.team_id 
    WHERE pl1 = 11 AND pl2 = 12
```

Or to find teams that consist only of these two players would be something like

```
SELECT * 
    FROM Team 
        JOIN PlayerLink AS pl1 ON Team.id = pl1.team_id 
        JOIN PlayerLink AS pl2 ON Team.id = pl.team_id 
        JOIN (
            Select Team.id, COUNT(*) AS size
                FROM Team
                    JOIN PlayerLink on Team.id = PlayerLInk.team_id
        ) AS t ON Team.id = t.id
    WHERE pl1 = 11 AND pl2 = 12 AND t.size = 2
```

## **Get to the point...**

How do I get this done with Active Record in rails? Can you think of a more efficient way of doing this?

## **Edit**

`PlayerLink.joins("JOIN player_links as pl2 ON pl2.team_id = player_links.team_id").where("player_links.player_id = 11 AND pl2.player_id = 12")`
Without any reasonable testing I believe this will get me what I want. I can then iterate through the results to see if they contain extra players and exclude them if I want.

This just *feels* inefficient to me. Any ideas on a better way?

Comment: please add playerlink model also

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Frist, has_many through is useful if you add additional fields to the connection (you named it playerLinks), if you do not have additional info has_and_belongs_to_many will do the job, see: https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-and-belongs-to-many-association

But for the has_many :through, make sure that you follow: https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association 
For you: `Physician -> Team`, `Patient -> Player`, `Appointment -> PlayerLinks`

Then you could do:

```
Team.find(<id>).players 
Player.find(<id>).teams
```

And since you have middle model, one or array of ids - to fetch for example relation to game date:

```
PlayerLinks.where(player: [<id>], team: [<id>])
```

Then if you want to get players from team `find` you would need to map results

```
Team.find([1,2]).players
```

**!** And finally to improve the query you should **preload association**:

```
Team.includes(:players).find([1,2]).map(&:players)
```

(The same goes form the Player perspective)

Since it is Rails (**convention before configuration**) you need to name your models accordingly (capitalized class name, file name singular, etc.) - so if it does not work, double check your associations, classes and files (`:player_links`, `player_links.rb`, `PlayerLink`)

I hope this helps!

Later edit, after understanding better what is asked:

To get teams containing player 1 and 2:

```
PlayerTeam.joins(:team).where(player_id: [1,2]).select(:team_id).group(:team_id).having("count(team_id) > 1")
```

To get the teams with only player 1 and 2:

```
PlayerLink.joins(:team).select('team_id, count(player_id)').group(:team_id).having("count(player_id) = sum(player_id in(1,2))")
```

For the second query be careful how you build query string, but probably you know that ;)

Comment: Thank you for all the time and effort you put into this. The solutions here are good for finding teams with a given player associated, but doesn't work when we need to find teams with 2 or more. You did give me an idea though. I hadn't thought of searching straight from the join table.

Comment: PlayerLink.joins("JOIN player_links as pl2 ON pl2.team_id = player_links.team_id").where("player_links.player_id = 1 AND pl2.player_id = 3")        gives me an array of results. This is good as a crude solution.

Comment: It works by the same principle: 
`PlayerLink.joins(:player).where(player_id: [1,2], team_ids: [1,2])` (or join on team if team is what you are looking for)

Comment: Use `join` or `include` to preload associations and query the models - you have 3 available. It is best to use active record as much as you can so whoever touches the project after you (or yourself later) has easier time ;)

Comment: That code will return an array of all PlayerLinks where the player has id 1 or 2 and the team has an id of 1 or 2. This will give me many more results than I want. I need a list of teams that have player 1 _and_ player 2 associated with it.

Comment: You are right, if I can do it with ActiveRecord then that's better. I just seems to have limits...

Comment: Huh, if I understand well you can help yourself with `having` in this case: 
`PlayerTeam.joins(:team).where(player_id: [1,2]).select(:team_id).group(:team_id).having("count(team_id) > 1")`
This results in:
`PlayerTeam Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "player_teams"."team_id" FROM "player_teams" INNER JOIN "teams" ON "teams"."id" = "player_teams"."team_id" WHERE "player_teams"."player_id" IN (?, ?) GROUP BY "player_teams"."team_id" HAVING (count(team_id) > 1) LIMIT ?  [["player_id", 1], ["player_id", 2], ["LIMIT", <whatever>]]`
List of teams containing player 1 and 2.

Comment: And finally teams with only players 1 and 2: 
`PlayerLink.joins(:team).select('team_id, count(player_id)').group(:team_id).having("count(player_id) = sum(player_id in(1,2))")`

Comment: I tried this code, so I named `player_links` => `player_teams` - if you see it somewhere, I will edit my response to clean that.